# Elasticsearch Multiple Cluster Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I just watched [Rafal Kuc's presentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/videos/scaling-massive-elasticsearch-clusters/)  and would like to use it for the basis of an Elastic Search Question.

If I added 50 million documents per day to a cluster where each day created a new index (time based [data design pattern](http://vimeo.com/44716955)), eventually in time that would get pretty big. For example sake we'll put the avg document at 15kb.

Now lets say I needed to do that for 10 years. Eventually, I would need to create multiple clusters. Can I create multiple clusters in ES and search them all simultaneously? Could I use an alias for something like this? Or is it not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, I think a search via the api or your client of choice (Java/Python/etc) is going to be against a single cluster.

Your client could make multiple requests one to each cluster, perhaps if you organized your clusters by years?

In theory a cluster could just grow forever, although at some point I would think the overhead of scattering and gathering a query to N nodes (where N is very very very large) would cause problems.

Comment: Good to know, thank you! But why wouldnt they build a multi threaded class into their API's so that you could simultaneously query N clusters at once, sort the returned scores and send the output in one json String?..

Comment: why is a query against N clusters (with N nodes each) better than querying N nodes in your cluster?